# getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri) No files supported by provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want store a file audio in my personal content provider.
i save record:

Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
OutputStream os =  getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

but getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri); throws:

10-13 19:44:53.903: ERROR/TAB(5679): No files supported by provider at content://com.memento.data.provider.MementoProvider/audionotes/6
10-13 19:44:53.903: ERROR/TAB(5679): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files supported by provider at content://com.memento.data.provider.MementoProvider/audionotes/6
10-13 19:44:53.903: ERROR/TAB(5679):     at android.content.ContentProvider.openFile(ContentProvider.java:585)

I have a column named _data for that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You are a little sparse here.  I presume you have a custom ContentProvider?

In any case take a look at [How to store large blobs in an android content provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883211/how-to-store-large-blobs-in-an-android-content-provider)

(I answered my own question there so I won't reproduce it here.)

It sounds like your ContentProvider isn't matching the uri.