# Storing file in Android Database (Custom Content Provider) using _data field - v1.6

Tags: android, file, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have been battling with an issue in my Android app. I have been reading Android docs, my book on Android (Andriod Pro 2) and have looked at almost each and every example I could get my hands on but could not figure out how to implement **storing of files (images, binary data) against records in Sqlite table exposed by the content provider**.

Here is what I have done (almost similar to Notepad sample app):

- Implemented `ContentProvider` in my provider. It all works for CRUD operations. Internally it uses an implementation `SQLiteOpenHelper` (pretty standard stuff)
- I have added a `_data` column of type text
- I insert a record and get the Uri back
- Call openOutputStream on the content provider and start writing the data

This is exactly according to the Android Pro 2 book.Here is the snippet of that part of code:

```
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MyAuthority.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
OutputStream s = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
```

But I get the error below:

> 11-29 01:07:30.717:
>   WARN/System.err(1490):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No
>   files supported by provider at
>   content://myproviderauthority/podcasts/1

What do I need to do? I read Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#creating) but they are very vague:

> the field that exposes the data to
>   clients should actually contain a
>   content: URI string.

**1) So does the field type need to be TEXT or is there a special `content: URI string` data type?**

**2) At the time of inserting I do not have the URI. Do I need to get the URI after insert and then update that field in the record?**

> The record should also have another
>   field, named "_data" that lists the
>   exact file path on the device for that
>   file. This field is not intended to be
>   read by the client, but by the
>   ContentResolver.

**3) So what should be the type of this field be? TEXT - I assume?**

> The client will call
>   ContentResolver.openInputStream() on
>   the user-facing field holding the URI
>   for the item.

**4) This is utter rubbish! How can I call `ContentResolver.openInputStream()` on the field?? You can only call this on the record and passing the Uri.**

Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me. I have also reviewed these SO questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883211/how-to-store-large-blobs-in-an-android-content-provider) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926553/getcontentresolver-openoutputstreamuri-no-files-supported-by-provider)) and they did not help.

*By the way I am building against Level 4 of the API (version 1.6).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see where "No files supported by provider at..." comes from, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883211/how-to-store-large-blobs-in-an-android-content-provider/4336013#4336013). The situation there seems very similar with the one you've described.

In short, your content provider (or some of its superclasses) needs to override and implement `openFile` method. That error is raised by the default "not implemented--back off!" code in `ContentProvider.java`.

I find it helpful to peek at underlying source code of the framework when I get stuck, since documentation is sometimes a bit lacking.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I had guessed, it involves implementing openFile but  there was no mention of it anywhere, certainly not in Google documentation. Now that I see it involves storing on a file anyway, it does not provide me with a benefit as I am not going to expose the file in my custom provider.