# How to return an image from my custom camera app called from other app via intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android

I managed to build a simple but working custom camera application.
So far I can launch it directly and have it taking photos.
I also added proper intent-filters to have it published as an available application to reply to intent calls of another application containing a line of code such as this one: `Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

The problem is: **How do I code my camera app to send back images to external apps that pass a URI for saving?**

Currently I have a method that detects whether the camera has been launched directly or invoked to reply to an intent-filter: this method is `isImageCaptureIntent` (working).

I suppose I have to write something in the `onPictureTaken` method of the `PictureCallback` but all attempts stop in NullPointerExceptions once I try to write to OutputStrems.

Note that `mSaveUri` is already filled with the proper URI provided by the calling application from this line of code: `mSaveUri = (Uri) myExtras.getParcelable( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT );`

Here is the method:

```
 PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {);

        if (isImageCaptureIntent()) {

            if (mSaveUri != null) {
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    outputStream = getContentResolver()
             .openOutputStream(mSaveUri);  <== HERE I GET NullPointerException
                    outputStream.write(arg0);
                    outputStream.close();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // ignore exception
                } finally {
                }
            } 
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

there are similar questions to this one.
one post says it's a problem on htc devices. here:

- [getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri) No files supported by provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926553/getcontentresolver-openoutputstreamuri-no-files-supported-by-provider)
- [null pointer exception in android camera application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300928/null-pointer-exception-in-android-camera-application)
- [NullPointerException when saving the path of an image taken by a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767683/nullpointerexception-when-saving-the-path-of-an-image-taken-by-a-picture)

in any case , i would suggest sending a request to capture an image , and receiving the path to it , and use MODE_WORLD_READABLE for the file , or use an external storage path .

Answer (score 0):

```
       mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);

        Matrix mtrxFreeze = new Matrix();
        mtrxFreeze.postRotate(90);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(),
                mBitmap.getHeight(), mtrxFreeze, true);
```